# Как сделать так чтобы этот код выводил не адрес, а число?

Tags: c++, c

Как сделать так чтобы этот код выводил не адрес, а число?
код:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void insertionSort(int array[], int n)
{
    int i, element, j;
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++) { element = array[i]; j = i - 1; while (j >= 0 && array[j] > element) {
            array[j + 1] = array[j];
            j = j - 1;
        }
        array[j + 1] = element;
    }
}

// Function to print the elements of an array
void printArray(int array[], int n)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d ", array[i]);
    printf("n");
}


int main(){

    int  array[3] = {1,3,4};

    insertionSort(&array[3],3 );
    printArray(&array[3],3);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: передавать `array` вместо `&array[3]`, собственно обращение к элементу с индексом 3 уже будет за пределами массива, как и вся индексация в фунции insertionSort

Comment: Или `&array[0]`, смысл тот же.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat в данном случае да, но не будет работать для популярного use-case с передачей одного аргумента без указания размера вторым аргументом `T(&arr)[N]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void insertionSort(int array[], int n)
{
    int i, element, j;
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        element = array[i];
        j = i - 1;
        while (j >= 0 && array[j] > element) {
            array[j + 1] = array[j];
            j = j - 1;
        }
        array[j + 1] = element;
    }
}

// Function to print the elements of an array
void printArray(int array[], int n)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d ", array[i]);
    printf("n");
}


int main(){

    int array[3] = {1, 3, 4};

    insertionSort(&array[0], 3);
    printArray(&array[0], 3);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: &array[0] это разве не обращение к нулевому индексу массива?

Comment: @komigor адрес первого элемента массива